# pyodbc locks tables and takes too long to run

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a python script to download files from an SFTP site to a local folder and then run a stored procedure using the downloaded file. The first aspect runs fine. But then the execution of the stored procedure causes a lock on other tables on the SQL server - returns "Timeout expired" error. The procedure has been running for an hour and half.

This is the syntax I used for the execution of the stored procedure in case anybody was wondering:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Db;UID=myid;PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""exec SP_Upsert_Y ?""",sfile)
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: Does the procedure take as long when run natively within the SQL Sever? Does it also lock the database when run that way?

Comment: No when i run the Stored proc straight up in sql server it's executed in like a minute or less and it does not lock the db.

Comment: What does the procedure do? Does it `BULK INSERT` the file or something similar? If so, is it possible that your Python code hasn't released the file? You also mentioned locking several times, how have you observed that locking is causing the problem? Have you used SQL Profiler to watch the procedure execution? Mentioning the version of SQL Server, Python and pyodbc may also be helpful.

Comment: Hi Pondlife. Yes the Stored Proc does bulk insert of the file to a temp table, some trimming and then insertion to a permanent table. I mentioned locking because when I try to access some tables, I receive the error "Lock Request time out period exceeded". I'm using the SQL Server 2012, python 2.7 and the latest version of pyodbc(I had easy_installed it- can't remember exactly what the version was). Thanks

Comment: Please post the code of the sproc and what is going on from SQL Profiler, if possible

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problemn and y solved add the parameter `autocommit=True` to connection string

Comment: same here... Executing the stored procedure via PYODBC caused the related tables to become locked until the entire procedure finished. When running the stored procedure from SSMS there was no issue, the locking was managed as expected (only locking during short transactions). Setting autocommit=True changed the behaviour similar to SSMS.